# How to SSH into a Cisco ASA firewall with Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cisco

Would like use powershell to do some monitoring of a VPN tunnel and if outage detected, auto reset the tunnel.

Can Windows powershell SSH into a Cisco ASA firewall for issuing a firewall command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [SSH module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/2.1).  I've only limited experience using it to change ILO passwords on HP servers.  However, I'm confident it can be leveraged for more elaborate work.

You can install with:

```
Install-Module Posh-SSH
```

Make sure to do this in an elevated console.  I'd also point out there are other SSH modules, I can't vouch even this much but you may want to play with them.  You can find them with something like:

```
Find-Module *SSH*
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since Windows 10 v1809, `ssh` is a built-in tool in Windows. You do not have to install anything else. Just issue:

```
ssh -l <USERNAME> <DNS/IP>
```

like on linux.